# Add a javascript function to download event on elfinder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, elfinder

I am using elFinder 2.1 and want to add a javascript function to the download event. This is to register the downloads and / or send a mail.

I want the function to trigger on doubleclick and on the download option.

i can add a getFileCallback: function (url) {} but i does work only on doubleclick on the file.

Where can i find the coding of the download option?
Where should i add my function?

Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#elfinder').elfinder({
    handlers: {
        download: function(event, elfinderInstance) {
            elfinderInstance.log(event); // print to browser console
        }
    },
    // and your options
});

// OR

var elfinderInstance = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
    // your options object
}).elfinder('instance')
.bind('download', function(event) {
    elfinderInstance.log(event); // print to browser console
});
```